# Javascript parseFloat with different ExponentIndicator

Tags: javascript, parsefloat

I want to parse the following string: `-3.755512109246D2` using javascript.
Please notice that this format uses `D` as exponent indicator instead of the usual `e` or `E`.

```
parseFloat("-3.755512109246D2")
```

will ignore the last part (`D2`) and return `-3.755512109246`.

Reading the spec I see that only `e` and `E` is used as the [ExponentIndicator](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-ExponentIndicator) and from a quick search it seems that these core functions are actually written in C++.

What are my options here? Take into account that I am parsing big files that will contain numbers with different formats, sometimes they will have an exponent, that exponent could be `e`, `E`, `d` and `D`.

If my only way is to rewrite `parseFloat` so now it treats the same way `D` and `d` as `E` what would be an efficient implementation?

My first bet would be something like:

```
var str ="-3.755512109246D2";
for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
{
    if(str[i] == 'd' || str[i] == 'D')
    {
        str[i] = 'E';
        break;
    }
}
var result = parseFloat(str);
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: `str[i]` is not assignable in JavaScript because `str` is a primitive.

Comment: JavaScript strings are immutable, but you can use `replace`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `replace` with a regular expression to replace a `d` or `D` with `e`, then `Number` instead of `parseFloat` to make sure the entire string is interpreted as a number and not just cut off at the first invalid part:

```
var result = Number(str.replace(/d/i, "e"));
```

`/d/i` matches the first “d” ASCII-case-insensitively.

Comment: Just be aware that this is not going to care whether the string is exponential or hexidecimal, e.g. `Number('0xd')` vs `Number('0xe')`.

Comment: This works, thank you. But, since I am not familiar with the performance of Regex in Javascript, I have another question: wouldn't it be much faster to copy the string char by char replacing the one of the ExponentIndicator?

Comment: @Sturm: Not necessarily, but you can benchmark and profile to find out.